# ReadBeanPHP не работает запрос из-за usleep()

Tags: php, mysql

Странная проблема, когда ставлю usleep больше 300000 в одном из циклов - любые запросы к БД через redbean php после такого цикла перестают работать. В чем может быть причина? Провозился 3 часа и ничего не нашел. Только ставлю usleep меньше 300000 - запросы сразу начинают идти отлично.

```
    <?php
    //header('Location:/index.php');
    ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
    require_once "config.php";

    //Выборка записанных в БД групп и очистка конечного массива от лишнего
    $groups = R::findAll('groups');
    $array = R::exportAll( $groups );
    $groupids =  array_column($array, 'group_id');

    //Общее количество постов которое должно у нас записаться (15 умноженное на количество групп)
    $maxpostscount = 15 * count($groupids);

    //Удаляем пустые массивы ID'ов ввведенных групп, перечисляем их через запятую
    $new_array = array_diff($groupids, array(''));
    $groupids = implode(",", $new_array);



    //Получаем точные циферные ID'ы
    $query = file_get_contents("https://api.vk.com/method/groups.getById?group_ids=".$groupids."&fields=description&v=5.80&access_token=".$access_token);
    $query = json_decode ($query,true);
    $query =  array_column($query['response'], 'id');
    $groupids = $query;



    //Получаем список постов, очищаем их, вбиваем нужные элементы массива в их ключи "gifsurl,texts" и тд..
    foreach ($groupids as $groupid)
    {
    $query = file_get_contents("https://api.vk.com/method/wall.get?owner_id=-".$groupid."&count=15&filter=ownerextended=1&v=5.80&offset=1&access_token=".$access_token);
    $query = json_decode ($query,true);
    $posts[] = $query['response']['items'];
//Если тут ставлю больше 300000 то все запросы к бд после этого цикла перестают работать        
usleep(300000);

    }

    $posts = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $posts); //Убираем лишнюю вложенность

    //Вбиваем нужные элементы при помощи цикла в их переменные, элементы взяты из запроса выше
    foreach ($posts as $post) {
//Если тут ставлю больше 300000 то все запросы к бд после этого цикла перестают работать    
usleep(700000);
    $query = file_get_contents("https://api.vk.com/method/likes.getList?type=post&owner_id=".$post['owner_id']."&item_id=".$post['id']."&filter=likes&friends_only=0&extended=0&offset=0&count=1&skip_own=0&v=5.80&access_token=".$access_token);
    $query = json_decode ($query,true);
    $postsarray[] = array(
        "gifsurl" => $post['attachments']['0']['doc']['url'],
        "texts" => $post['text'],
        "likes_count" => $query['response']['count'],
    );

    }


    //Стоп слова
    foreach($postsarray as $key => $value) {
        foreach($value as $k => $v) {
            if (empty($v) || (preg_match('/http/', $v) && $k == 'text')) {
                unset($postsarray[$key]);
            }
        }
    }
    //Тестовый запрос к бд
        vardump($postsarray);
        $postinfo = R::dispense( 'postslist' );
        $postinfo->texts = 'hello';
        $id = R::store( $postinfo );

    ?>
```

Comment: Warning: Error while sending QUERY packet. PID=28238 in /home/j/jizziioc/test/public_html/rb-mysql.php on line 747 Fatal error: Uncaught [HY000] - SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away trace: #0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Видимо заканчивается время ожидания сервера. Может быть оно задано на сервере mysql (wait_timeout, interactive_timeout).

Возможно задано в свойствах подключения вашего фреймворка

При этом отдает ошибку "MySQL Server Has Gone Away"

Comment: ini_set('mysql.connect_timeout', 31536000);
ini_set('wait_timeoutt', 28800);
ini_set('interactive_timeout', 28800); добавил такие настройки в скрипт, проблема не решилась.

Comment: Похоже, что в фреймворке при коннекте устанавливается таймаут.